# MinHeap and MaxHeap implementation in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to know if java has any collection that can help me with minheap and maxheap implementation.
I know I can use PriortyQueue data structure to implement maxheap.
Can we use same for minheap? If yes, How?

Thanks,
Manan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it backwards: a heap is a way of implementing a priority queue. As for the min / max part, simply write the appropriate `Comparator` classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have your levels of abstraction a bit backwards on this.

A heap is a tree like ( note, it doesn't actually have to have a tree, but rather a method of relating points of data to their "children" ( see below for more )) data-structure which has very specific relation between nodes and their children.

A priority queue, in contrast, is a more abstract idea. It is a queue ( list like data structure with a FIFO data access model ) but rather than being actually FIFO it rather returns the object of greatest priority first.

Just like how, in a heap, there are different ways of implementing the underlying structure, so too in a priority queue one could do many different things. The benefit to using a heap as the underlying structure of the priority queue is that you don't have to do any more work. Just heap the values based on their priority and when someone requests a value return the head.

The major difference is that the heap is defined by it's tree like property and the heap constraint where as a priority queue is only defined by how it interacts with others.

```
// A note on creating heaps
// Given that A is an array of n values indexed from 1 to n
// We can model a tree like structure buy stating that for any
// value i in (1,n) it's children are 2 * i and 2 * i + 1
// So with an array you can easily model a heap in this manner
```

Comment: So it mean inserting into priority queue is O(n)? If that is the case do I need to write my own Tree like heap?

Comment: Appending to a regular queue should be `O(1)` if implemented properly. As for inserting into a Priority queue it depends on what kind of underlying data structure you are using. If you are using a List stricture ( like a LinkedList ) then inserting will be `O(n)` because you have to walk the entire list to insert. If you use a tree like structure ( say a heap ) then insert costs `O(log n)` because that is the cost of inserting into a tree. Priority Queue is a bit of a misnomer. It doesn't function like a queue generally.

Comment: what does inbuilt PriorityQueue use in Java? tree or Queue?

Comment: I have no idea - I assume a heap like structure. That is a fairly standard way of doing it.